# React Js : React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: reactjs

I am making an api call with `request.get`. When I do setstate inside `request.get` callback function i am getting this error

My Error : -

```
  16 |     },function(err,resp,body){
  17 |         var data = JSON.parse(body)
  18 |         console.log(data)
> 19 |         that.setState({internship_data:data})
  20 |     })
  21 | }
  22 | render(){
```

My code : -

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import '../assets/styles/internship_form.css'
import {Collapse} from 'react-bootstrap'
import request from 'request'

class Support extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            internship_data:null
        }
    } 
    componentWillMount(){
        const that = this;
        var internship_id = this.props.params.id;
        var data = null
        request.get({
            url:`http://www.myapi.com:1441/internshipbuffer/${internship_id}`,
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('auth-token')}`
            }
        },function(err,resp,body){
            var data = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log(data)
            that.setState({internship_data:data})
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.internship_data ? this.renderContent() : this.renderLoading()
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
    renderLoading = () => {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop:'100px'}}>Loading....</div>
        )
    }
    renderContent = () => {
        // const that = this;
        var data = this.state.internship_data;
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img alt="Brand Logo" src={data.asset_url} className="img-circle" id="brand-logo" width="50"/>
                </div>
                <ul className="card-brand-info-container">
                    <li>{data.brand_name}</li>
                    <li>Brand manager: {data.brand_manager}</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="review-btn" onClick={this.reviewAction} >Review</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="reject-btn" >Reject</button>

                <Collapse isOpened={this.state.isOpened} className="hidden-brand-info" >
                    <div>Title : {data.position_name}</div>
                        <div>Description : {data.description}</div>
                        <div>Positions : {data.postions}</div>
                        <div>Intenship Period : {data.period} </div>
                        <div>
                            Benefits :
                            {/* <ul className="benefits-list">
                                {data.benefits && data.benefits.map(function(item,i){
                                    return <li key={i} >{i+1}.{item}</li>
                                })}
                            </ul> */}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Skills & Requirements :
                            {/* <ul className="skills-list">
                                {data.benefits.map(function(item,i){
                                    return <li key={i} >{i+1}.{item}</li>
                                })}
                            </ul> */}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            City :
                            <ul className="city-list">
                                {/* {
                                    data.city.map(function(item,i){
                                        if (i !== (that.props.data.city.length)-1)
                                            return <li key={i} >{item},</li>
                                        else
                                            return <li key={i} >{item}</li>

                                    })
                                } */}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="action-btns" >
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="approve-btn" >Approve</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="support-btn" >Support</button>
                        </div>
                </Collapse>
                <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 className="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Support
```

My data variable : -

```
data =
{
  "brand":"59b52b3690c28428d945b8f2",
  "brandmanager":"59b3f204cbc3c72510c8acfd",
  "moderation":true,
  "createdAt":"2017-09-14T06:21:21.893Z",
  "updatedAt":"2017-09-14T06:21:21.893Z",
  "id":"59ba1fe190c28428d945b8f4"
}
```

Comment: Your error is related to your components render. Please add the render code too. Please add the complete error and also please add the log result for `data`

Comment: You should use a fat arrow function for the success callback to keep your `this` binding to the component. You shouldn't have to do `const that = this;`.

Comment: @bennygenel . Edited accordingly .
Pls help. Thanks !

Comment: Whats that `Collapse` component? Is it from a library? Also you have a extra `{` at the end of the code. Is it a typo of the question? You still didn't add the data.

Comment: Now i have put my whole `Support` Component above.
What data are you talking about ?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda . can you give an example ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you have more than one (main) Component in render method. It should be only one main Component or html tag in render method according to the docs.

```
class Executioner extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children)()
  }
}
```

This returns the only child in this.props.children. If there is more than one child, it throws an error, thusly grinding the entire app to a halt—perfect to avoid lazy devs trying to mess with our component.

see more here: http://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/

**UPDATED**

After a while of investigation I found was what the problem. The `<Collapse>`component should have ONE main html node. You should wrap the content of the `<Collapse>` in e.g. `<div>` like so:

```
<Collapse isOpened={this.state.isOpened} className="hidden-brand-info" >
                <div>
                    <div>Title : {data.position_name}</div>
                        <div>Description : {data.description}</div>
                        <div>Positions : {data.postions}</div>
                        <div>Intenship Period : {data.period} </div>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            City :
                            <ul className="city-list">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="action-btns" >
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="approve-btn" >Approve</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="support-btn" >Support</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </Collapse>
```

Also it looks like the `<Collapse>` does not have a `isOpened` prop and a `className`. 
You have also missed to declare one method `reviewAction` which you try to use in this line of code:
`<button type="button" className="btn btn-default" id="review-btn" onClick={this.reviewAction} >Review</button>`

Comment: Can you provide a solution based on the edits now ?
I have provided my full code.

Comment: I can't test it got
GET 401 (Unauthorized)
bundle.js?ba50e4811e0a946d1160:47086 {msg: "Malformed token supplied", code: 4300, status: 401}.

Could you paste value of "data" from var data = JSON.parse(body)?

Comment: You didn't paste all the code and there are a few bits missing but I do not think that problem is at the line you pointing. Have you tried removed everything apart one <div> from render method? Just to be sure that there isn't something more causing the error.

Comment: Hey i copy pasted my whole page `support.jsx` file . 
Also added data variable question.Let me knw what else info you want .
Thanks !

Comment: Yes got it. 
Anyway, lateer found that ,i  didn't want collapse in the first place .
Now eveything is solved !
Thanks !